# How to seek with GPUImageMovie with AVMutableComposition

Tags: ios, ios9, gpuimage

I have an `AVMutableComposition` (which is an `AVAsset`) and I'm using `GPUImage` (https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) to filter it by using a `GPUImageMovie`. It is working, but I need to implement seeking functionality.

I'm currently initializing `GPUImageMovie` with my mutable composition:

`[[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithAsset:asset];`

However, according to [GPUImageMovie playback controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781359/gpuimagemovie-playback-controls) I need to create my own player and player item, then initialize the movie with that:

```
videoPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
videoPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:videoPlayerItem];
GPUImageMovie *video = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithPlayerItem:videoPlayerItem];
```

However, when I try to play the movie this way using `[videoPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero]; [videoPlayer play];`, I'm getting a blank player. Nothing is `nil` etc, but it simply doesn't show anything.

The only question/answer I could find was this:

[GPUImageMovie not playing video file when initWithPlayerItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084583/gpuimagemovie-not-playing-video-file-when-initwithplayeritem)

Though its solution is irrelevant to me as the problem was with the URL scheme, which I don't have (mine is not a URL asset, but a mutable composition).

How can I control/seek an `AVMutableComposition` played as a `GPUImageMovie`? (and yes, I need to use `GPUImageMovie`, the whole processing pipeline is tightly-coupled to use that) (I am targeting iOS 9+)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Disclosure: this is a workaround, not a real solution.**

I've ended up creating a new `AVPlayer` based on the original video, and used that one for controlling the playback. Of course, even if it suited my needs for this particular project (as I didn't need the filtered video at the point where I needed to control playback), it may not fit everybody's needs.