# GPUImageMovie use multiple images as textures and process

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, gpuimage

I'm trying to use a few `GPUImagePicture`s as texture sources along with a fragment shader for filtering a playing video.

I'm able to process still images great in this manner, but I cannot seem to figure out what I'm missing to get this to work on a `GPUImageMovie` I'd appreciate any help offered.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) GPUImageView *gpuPlayerView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) GPUImageMovie *gpuMovie;

AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:self.video];

self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

self.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

[self.player play];

self.gpuMovie = [[GPUImageMovie alloc]initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

self.gpuMovie.playAtActualSpeed = YES;

GPUImagePicture *sourcePicture1 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc]initWithImage:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"FilterBG"]];

GPUImagePicture *sourcePicture2 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc]initWithImage:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"FilterOverlay"]];

GPUImagePicture *sourcePicture3 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc]initWithImage:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"Filter1Map"]];

GPUImageFilter *filter = [[GPUImageFourInputFilter alloc]initWithFragmentShaderFromString:
kFilter1ShaderString];

[self.gpuMovie addTarget:filter atTextureLocation:0];

if (sourcePicture1)
{
    [sourcePicture1 addTarget:filter atTextureLocation:1];
}

if (sourcePicture2)
{
    [sourcePicture2 addTarget:filter atTextureLocation:2];
}

if (sourcePicture3)
{
    [sourcePicture3 addTarget:filter atTextureLocation:3];
}

[filter addTarget:self.gpuPlayerView];

[self.gpuMovie startProcessing];
```

Comment: Please try looking on this might be helpful.. [GPUImageMovie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799836/gpuimagemovie-pause-while-applying-filter).

Comment: Do you have any minimal project to share illustrating your problem?

Comment: Where did you get your implementation of GPUImageFourInputFilter? I'm assuming it was based on the GPUImageTwoInputFilter or GPUImageThreeInputFilter classes that ship with the framework. You might want to check in that class to make sure it is propagating timestamps appropriately for updating content. Test out the above with a GPUImageTwoInputFilter or GPUImageThreeInputFilter and fewer blend images to see if this is localized to your GPUImageFourInputFilter implementation.

Comment: @BradLarson I made a few subclasses of `GPUImageFilter` up to `GPUImageSixInputFilter`, and haven't had any issues with processing still images, only video. I can post my code for the `GPUImageFourInputFilter` if you'd like.

Comment: I believe the trickiest part is getting the `-newFrameReadyAtTime:` override correct. Otherwise, the frames don't output properly and wait around forever for the still photos to update (which they never would). That's why I'd try with the stock versions with fewer inputs and see if they process correctly. It's something to do with indefinite time inputs (still images) and timestamped ones (movies, video).

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work with a `GPUImageTwoInputFilter` either.

Comment: @aviatorken89 Great job! can you share it to me ? I make the same job, but there's something wrong with some custom filters that has six input texture.

Answer (score -1):

There is a method which you can use to achieve the same

> CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage

which allows a shared buffer between a GL texture and a movie.
In this Core Video OpenGLES texture caches are used to cache and manage CVOpenGLESTextureRef textures. These texture caches provide you with a way to directly read and write buffers with various pixel formats, such as 420v or BGRA, from GLES.

```
//Mapping a BGRA buffer as a source texture:
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, textureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &outTexture);
//Mapping a BGRA buffer as a renderbuffer:
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, textureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8_OES, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &outTexture);
//Mapping the luma plane of a 420v buffer as a source texture:
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, textureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LUMINANCE, width, height, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &outTexture);
//Mapping the chroma plane of a 420v buffer as a source texture:
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, textureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, width/2, height/2, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 1, &outTexture);
//Mapping a yuvs buffer as a source texture (note: yuvs/f and 2vuy are unpacked and resampled -- not colorspace converted)
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, textureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB_422_APPLE, width, height, GL_RGB_422_APPLE, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_8_8_APPLE, 1, &outTexture);

    CVReturn CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage ( CFAllocatorRef
    __nullable allocator, CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef __nonnull textureCache, CVImageBufferRef __nonnull sourceImage, CFDictionaryRef
    __nullable textureAttributes, GLenum target, GLint internalFormat, GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLenum format, GLenum type, size_t planeIndex, CVOpenGLESTextureRef __nullable * __nonnull textureOut );
```

This function either creates a new or returns a cached CVOpenGLESTextureRef texture object mapped to the CVImageBufferRef and associated parameters. This operation creates a live binding between the image buffer and the underlying texture object.

I hope that will help you in creating what is required :)

Comment: is this code taking a CVPixelBufferRef and overlay an image onto of it while taking advantage of the GPU.  Sorry I am a beginner at OpenGLES.  And then does the last line return a CVPixelBufferRef that has both images combined?

Answer (score -2):

I have tried `GPUImage`’s sample code (`SimpleVideoFileFilter`) to achieve your output. I have created `GPUImageFilterGroup` and adding filters to it. To add images as texture, I have used the code of `GPUImageMissEtikateFilter` filter. Here is my code :

```
NSURL *sampleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sample_iPod" withExtension:@"m4v"];

movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:sampleURL];
movieFile.runBenchmark = YES;
movieFile.playAtActualSpeed = YES;
// filter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] initWithFragmentShaderFromFile:@"CustomFilter"];

filter = [[GPUImageFilterGroup alloc] init];

GPUImageSaturationFilter *saturationFilter = [[GPUImageSaturationFilter alloc] init];
[(GPUImageSaturationFilter *)saturationFilter setSaturation:0.0];
[(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filter addFilter:saturationFilter];

GPUImagePicture *lookupImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lookup_miss_etikate"]];
GPUImageLookupFilter *lookupFilter = [[GPUImageLookupFilter alloc] init];
[(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filter addFilter:lookupFilter];

[lookupImageSource addTarget:lookupFilter atTextureLocation:1];
[lookupImageSource processImage];

[saturationFilter addTarget:lookupFilter];

[(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filter setInitialFilters:@[saturationFilter]];
[(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filter setTerminalFilter:lookupFilter];

[movieFile addTarget:filter];

// Only rotate the video for display, leave orientation the same for recording
GPUImageView *filterView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
[filter addTarget:filterView];

[movieFile startProcessing];
```

Hoping this will help you.

Comment: I need to use a fragment shader and also I'm using `GPUImagePicture`s, and not `GPUImageLookupFilter`s.

Answer (score -2):

After the initialization of your GPUImage:

```
GPUImagePicture *sourcePicture1 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FilterBG"]];
```

you must call:

```
[sourcePicture1 processImage];
```

to effectively load the image and make it available to the GPUImage pipeline.

And do the same for `sourcePicture2` and `sourcePicture3`.

Update:

What I needed to do a few years ago when I used it with movies and pictures, was to add a notification when the movie was loaded and ready to play (in GPUImageMovie.m, `processAsset`method, before `self.decodeIsAllowed = YES;`. Only when the movie was ready, I set its GPUImage pipeline target.